# my bot get this error,its js but i dont understand why i get this

Tags: javascript

**i host this bot on rdp!I put my bot to more servers but i dont understand why i get this...**
after restart i dont get again this problem its from rdp?
but i dont think this problem its from internet or other,i give u more info if u need ,just reply
i have an an setup command cuz bot create an ticket and log channels

```
Error [ERR_UNHANDLED_ERROR]: Unhandled error. (ErrorEvent {
  target: WebSocket {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      message: [Function],
      open: [Function],
      error: [Function],
      close: [Function]
    },
    _eventsCount: 4,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    readyState: 2,
    protocol: '',
    _binaryType: 'nodebuffer',
    _closeFrameReceived: false,
    _closeFrameSent: false,
    _closeMessage: '',
    _closeTimer: null,
    _closeCode: 1006,
    _extensions: {},
    _receiver: null,
    _sender: null,
    _socket: null,
    _isServer: false,
    _redirects: 0,
    url: 'wss://gateway.discord.gg/?v=6&encoding=json',
    _req: ClientRequest {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 5,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      outputData: [],
      outputSize: 0,
      writable: true,
      _last: true,
      chunkedEncoding: false,
      shouldKeepAlive: true,
      useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
      sendDate: false,
      _removedConnection: false,
      _removedContLen: false,
      _removedTE: false,
      _contentLength: 0,
      _hasBody: true,
      _trailer: '',
      finished: true,
      _headerSent: true,
      socket: [TLSSocket],
      connection: [TLSSocket],
      _header: 'GET /?v=6&encoding=json HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
        'Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13\r\n' +
        'Sec-WebSocket-Key: VBoBwwuw5bAD1SNRbzza+A==\r\n' +
        'Connection: Upgrade\r\n' +
        'Upgrade: websocket\r\n' +
        'Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits\r\n' +
        'Host: gateway.discord.gg\r\n' +
        '\r\n',
      _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
      agent: undefined,
      socketPath: undefined,
      method: 'GET',
      insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
      path: '/?v=6&encoding=json',
      _ended: false,
      res: [IncomingMessage],
      aborted: true,
      timeoutCb: null,
      upgradeOrConnect: false,
      parser: [HTTPParser],
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      reusedSocket: false,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
      [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype]
    },
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
  },
  type: 'error',
  message: 'Unexpected server response: 520',
  error: Error: Unexpected server response: 520
      at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Users\TheAdrian\Desktop\bot mod\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:595:7)
      at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:315:20)
      at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (_http_client.js:596:27)
      at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:119:17)
      at HTTPParser.execute (<anonymous>)
      at TLSSocket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:469:22)
      at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
      at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:295:12)
      at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:271:9)
      at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:212:10)
})
    at Client.emit (events.js:304:17)
    at WebSocketConnection.onError (C:\Users\TheAdrian\Desktop\bot mod\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:374:17)
    at WebSocket.onError (C:\Users\TheAdrian\Desktop\bot mod\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:128:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at abortHandshake (C:\Users\TheAdrian\Desktop\bot mod\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:718:15)
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Users\TheAdrian\Desktop\bot mod\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:595:7)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (_http_client.js:596:27)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:119:17)
    at HTTPParser.execute (<anonymous>) {
  code: 'ERR_UNHANDLED_ERROR',
  context: ErrorEvent {
    target: WebSocket {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 4,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      readyState: 2,
      protocol: '',
      _binaryType: 'nodebuffer',
      _closeFrameReceived: false,
      _closeFrameSent: false,
      _closeMessage: '',
      _closeTimer: null,
      _closeCode: 1006,
      _extensions: {},
      _receiver: null,
      _sender: null,
      _socket: null,
      _isServer: false,
      _redirects: 0,
      url: 'wss://gateway.discord.gg/?v=6&encoding=json',
      _req: [ClientRequest],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    type: 'error',
    message: 'Unexpected server response: 520',
    error: Error: Unexpected server response: 520
        at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Users\TheAdrian\Desktop\bot mod\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:595:7)
        at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:315:20)
        at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (_http_client.js:596:27)
        at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:119:17)
        at HTTPParser.execute (<anonymous>)
        at TLSSocket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:469:22)
        at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
        at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:295:12)
        at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:271:9)
        at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:212:10)
  }
}
```

Comment: may be https://support.exabytes.com.my/en/support/solutions/articles/14000100763-error-520-web-server-is-returning-an-unknown-error can help you understand what could have been the root cause as you are the only one who knew the environment and context of your feature and the problem.

Comment: [message: 'Unexpected server response: 520'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#520) check the logs on your server